# displaying more than one result in a saved search if item string field has 4 commas sep value

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I need to create a saved search on NetSuite
if I search for an item and show specified item fields in the results, I get the one item followed by the specified fields.

ex.)  Item      |       Description     |     Image codes (1 or more codes separated by commas)
baseball      old used baseball        145655, 234556342, 234656324
Shoes         new cool shoes           6454645, 5356633
shirt         blue and green shirt     645235, 6575221, 6524654

I need to show the data like so:
Code       |       Description     |   Item
145655         old used baseball       baseball
234556342      old used baseball       baseball
234656324      old used baseball       baseball

Haven't tried anything.